# Taking things out of one list and putting them in another (python)

Tags: python, list

I'm working some code for my second ever assignment, a Go Fish game in python. For one of my function definitions, I need to take out the target_rank out of the target_player list of cards, and append it to the current players card list. I have tried using for loops, but receive errors for changing the length of the list. So far the code I have is

```
def Hit(player_number, target_player, target_rank, pHands):
    while str(target_rank) in pHands[target_player]:
       pHands[player_number].append(pHands[target_player].pop(target_rank))
    print pHands[player_number]
    print pHands[target_player]
pHands = [['a', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', 't'], ['2', 'q', '6', '9', '5', 'k', 'k', 'a', '3', '8'], ['j', '9', 't', 't', '2', 't', '7', 'j', '5', '9'], ['8', '8', 'a', 'q', 'k', '4', '6', '9', 'q', '2']]
Hit (0,1,'a',pHands)
```

Where pHands is a list of lists of the players card. I understand I can't use pop since target rank is a string and not the place value, but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Try to use only one variable naming convention throughout your code.  Check out [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for more info.  I prefer `lower_case_with_underscores`. Also, function names should be lower case.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be clearer not to chain the `pop` with the `append`. Moreover, `pop` requires an index number, not the card value itself, so it is a little awkward to use here. Instead, you could use `remove`:

```
def Hit(player_number, target_player, target_rank, pHands):
    while target_rank in pHands[target_player]:
        pHands[target_player].remove(target_rank)
        pHands[player_number].append(target_rank)
    print pHands[player_number]
    print pHands[target_player]
```

However, [`pop` and `remove` are `O(n)` operations](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Doing that once for every card in `pHands[target_player]` makes the `while-loop` `O(n**2)`. It would be better if we could perform the task in `O(n)`, and that is possible with [`append`, which is an `O(1)` operation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). So if all we need to do is `append` once for each card in `pHands[target_player]`, then the `for-loop` (below) is `O(n)`:

```
def Hit(player_number, target_player, target_rank, pHands):
    new_target_hand = []
    for card in pHands[target_player]:
        if target_rank == card:
            pHands[player_number].append(card)
        else:
            new_target_hand.append(card)
    pHands[target_player] = new_target_hand
    print pHands[player_number]
    print pHands[target_player]
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Mine works but [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888462/2607594) one is cleaner.

```
def Hit(player_number, target_player, target_rank, pHands):
    try:
        while True:
           pHands[player_number].append(pHands[target_player].pop(pHands.index(target_rank)))
        print pHands[player_number]
        print pHands[target_player]
    except ValueError:
        pass # value no longer in hand
pHands = [['a', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', 't'], ['2', 'q', '6', '9', '5', 'k', 'k', 'a', '3', '8'], ['j', '9', 't', 't', '2', 't', '7', 'j', '5', '9'], ['8', '8', 'a', 'q', 'k', '4', '6', '9', 'q', '2']]
Hit (0,1,'a',pHands)
```

Comment: Thanks! Still getting used to stack overflow.